# Can you change $_POST into something different

Tags: php, forms, post, controllers

I made two separate databases for my posts, one for article and one for review.

My two database tables, are basically the same.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `post_text` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `post_img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `post_pic` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For articles I used controller:

```
 function index_ajax()
    {
        echo "\$_POST:<br>";
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    function index_post()
    {
        echo "\$_POST:<br>";
        var_dump($_POST);
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $data['post_id'] = $this->params[0];
        insert('post', $data);
    }
```

Now I needed make basically same for review posts.

```
function index_ajax()
    {
        echo "\$_REVIEW :<br>";
        var_dump($_REVIEW);
    }

    function index_review()
    {
        echo "\$_REVIEW:<br>";
        var_dump($_REVIEW);
        $data = $_REVIEW['data'];
        $data['review_id'] = $this->params[0];
        insert('review', $data);
    }
```

The articles are going nicely into database, but the same method wont work for reviews.

I did change in my form from `<form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form">` to `<form class="form-inline" method="review" role="form">`

I have kind of feeling it wont just work for it

I heard it should work, but it doesn't actually. I am grateful for new tips and ideas.

Thank you!

**Update.** For someone who reads this in future.

```
 function index_ajax()
    {
        echo "\$_POST:<br>";
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    function index_post()
    {
        echo "\$_POST:<br>";
        var_dump($_POST);
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $data['review_id'] = $this->params[0];
        insert('review', $data);
    }
```

Comment: There is no `$_REVIEW` superglobal array.  Use `$_POST`.

Comment: Sorry, you can only use [official methods listed by RFC standards](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). "I heard it should work" where exactly did you "hear" this?

Comment: Well, before coming here I asked around people.Thank you. I tough so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is the http request type. 'Get' is for just getting the data from the page whereas 'post' is submitting data to the page.

[Read this.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Data submitted to the page is always going to live inside `$_POST`.

Comment: I actually read those before. Maybe because it didn't inserted with the `$_POST` at firsttime, I moved one.
 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two methods GET and POST . You can put the value of $_POST in to $_REVIEW.
Something like this $_REVIEW=$_POST.

Comment: Sure it did. The problem you're having is that $_REVIEW isn't global like $_POST is. To use it in that fashion you'd have to add `global $_REVIEW;` at the start of the function.